# Discord.JS How to use args

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to use args [] but I don't know how to make it work somehow.

I want to set an emoji and then write something that bot will post it. for example:

```
  .setDescription(`emoji args[0]\n\nEmoji2 args[1]`)
```

so it outputs to the channel

**1st line -> emoji MyText
2nd line -> Emoji2 MySecondText**

Comment: See [how to use template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

From MDN docs about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the **dollar sign and curly braces** (`${expression}`).

```js
const args = ["", ""];
console.log(`Emoji1: ${args[0]}\n\nEmoji2: ${args[1]}`);
```

Comment: .setDescription(`<a:important:878247757817741314> **Restocked** <a:important:878247757817741314> \n\n<a:nitro:878247785948917770> Nitro: **${args[0]}**\n\n <a:boost:878247790201933855> Boost: **${args[1]}**


When I write for the first line the number 10 and for second line the number 20 it takes only number 20 how to fix it?

Comment: Probably wrong argument handling, `console.log(args)` to see if all of your arguments are there, if no, you probably wrongly extracted the arguments from the message or however you get the arguments.